# I want to display some character data to the specific integer value stored in database table as 1,2 and 3

Tags: php, html, underscore.js

i want to display character data to some specific integer value stored in the database table as 1,2 and 3. I already fetched the integer value from the database table, want to convert it to character data. The data type used here is **enum**.Iam using **underscorejs** framework Please help

1 as **Six Pack**,

2 as **Thin** and

3 as **Fat**

```
if (! empty($timeline['bodybuild'])) {
$themeData['info_bodybuild_row'] = \SocialKit\UI::view('timeline/user/info-bodybuild-row');}
```

I Have the enum value in **$themeData['info_bodybuild_row']**

Comment: @AlivetoDie now its fetching the enum values ,i want to change it to specific string as i mentioned above

Comment: @AlivetoDie i have updated my question above. please check it